# How to save the JS output to a file

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs

I have the following JS that is run using phantomjs.

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var system = require('system');
var page = webPage.create();
page.customHeaders = {
  "pragma": "akamai-x-feo-trace"
};
if (system.args.length === 1) {
    console.log('Try to pass some args when invoking this script!');
} else {
    page.open(system.args[1], function (status) {
        var content = page.content;
        console.log('Content: ' + content);
        phantom.exit();
    });
}
```

I wanto to save the output of `console.log('Content: ' + content);` to a folder with `./html/<random#>.html`.

How should I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you only want to save the page content. You can use the [Filesystem module](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/) to [write](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/method/write.html) the content to a file. A random filename can be generated by invoking `''+(Math.random()*100000000000000000)+'.html'`.